# Meaning of .type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a bit confused about what happens when we write something like `UIView.type`. What is `type`?

Consider the following:

```
struct myClass {
    var viewType : UIView.Type
    var justView: UIView
}
```

The first returns to us `UIView.Type`, and the second is just `UIView`.

What is the difference? `UIView` is class, so we can treat that variable like any `UIView`. What is the point of using `UIView.type`?

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/types-and-meta-types-in-swift-9cd59ba92295

Comment: Metatypes can be tricky. I think you could best learn about them and see them in action in Smalltalk or Objective C

Comment: @Alexander why should i study them in Obj-C when i use Swift?

Comment: Essentially, initializes and `class` and `static` functions/properties of a type `T` don't belong to an instance of type `T` (like instance functions and properties do), but rather, they can be thought of as members of the metatype, `T.Type`.

Comment: Because you don't see them as much in Swift. E.g. when you do `[[NSArray alloc] init]`, you're sending the `alloc` message to `NSArray`. But `NSArray` isn't an object, it's a class, how can it receive messages? Well actually, `NSArray` is an instance of a metaclass. Class methods like `alloc` are actually instance members of `NSArray`'s metaclass

Comment: The usefulness of this is that it unifies the message mechanics of instance and class methods, because both instance and class methods can be thought of as just instance methods. Instance methods are members of the type, whereas class methods are instance members of the metatype.

Comment: I think the best way to master this would be to poke in a  smalltalk environment a bit.

Comment: @Alexander to simplify what u saying, you mean that alloc is sending for class.type, and init to class itself?

Comment: Yes. `alloc` is a message sent to `NSArray` (which is an instance of the `NSArray` metatype, spelt `NSArray.Type` in Swift). It returns a newly allocated instance (object) of `NSArray`, to which `init` is sent.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for your help now it become clearer for me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164417/discussion-between-alexander-and-evgeniy-kleban).